# Wordpress restoring an old database

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-database

I am trying to restore an old (circa 2017 or so) wordpress blog.
All i have is the database.
The database version is as follows

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `wp_options` where option_name = 'db_version';
+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name | option_value | autoload |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
|        49 | db_version  | 38590        | yes      |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When i point `wordpress:latest` at the db the screen comes up blank.
`/wp-admin` gives me a log-in screen, but upon log-in it goes to a blank screen.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: are the wordpress FILES from that same backup 2017, or you have latest WP files and want to run that with only an old DB?

Comment: @Ron I do not have any of the old WP files just the database. I would like to run a new (latest) version of WP if possible

Comment: using a very old DB on the latest file-base will most probably not work.. What you have in the DB can be studied and mapped to the new DB structure, and imported on portions.. depending on how important this is for you, you might get someone experienced with WP programmer to do this for you... Of course you can try, but JUST trying to import it.. as you see does not work as the DB structure has changed drastically over those 3years

Comment: Maybe you can download the old version (like from this link: https://wordpress.org/download/releases/) and then, if it work fine, to make little update to today and watch if all work again...